# Silverlight browser-in app doesn't work in different machine

Tags: c#, silverlight, certificate

I have a Silverlight application executed within a browser that uses the scanner by WIA, I configured my server and my client (I allowed Silverlight to elevated trust in browser, 
I signed the xap after I installed the certificate into Trusted Editors and Trust root (into the machine store) , change the registry value,etc all wich it's specified in http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/40466/ShowPost.aspx) and when I've published in my local IIS and I load the test page from the same machine: the application works but when i've tried to access to the page from another machine (with internet explorer with a low secured settings and Runned as administrator) I got the exception with the message  this operation is not supported in the current context.

what's wrong?

can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official Microsoft guide for allowing elevated trust in browser:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx

See: 1.Configure the target computers to allow trusted applications inside the browser by setting the following registry key:

And I don't think you can use a self signed certificate.

Comment: I know... but why works when I load the app in a browser in the local machine where it's installed and doesn't work from another machine ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have added the registry key on the machine that is not working.  A self signed certificate will only work on the machine that certificate was created on, not another machine.  You will need to sign the app with a valid certificate for it to work outside of your local (development) machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to install the certificate on each individual machine you intend to use the app on?

The certificate may work fine run from local host as it uses the test certificate, but is different when accessed from the server.

This would make sense as the elevated trust setting is made for enterprise use.

Check this blog post out, it's a really good guide on how to set up a trusted app.

[Silverlight 5 Trusted applications](http://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications)